# Keycloak - 500 Internal Server Error- when validating a token generated by a confidential client

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

In the Keycloak server, we created a client that has an `Access Type` of `confidential`.
By calling `/protocol/openid-connect/token` endpoint with the `client_id` and the `client_secret`, we got the `access_token`, which was supposed to authenticate the application (client) in question in the follow-up requests.

Even though the token is valid (which I double-checked by calling the `introspect` endpoint), I am getting a 500 Error from the server for any request that has this `access_token`

So in short:

- Calling this endpoint `<base_url>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token` gives an access_token

  - Provided data: client_id,client_secret, grant_type: "client_credentials"
- Calling `<base_url>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` gives `500Internal Server Error`

```
{
    "error": "unknown_error"
}
```

Any insights on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in Keycloak 13.0.0.
See this commit: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/056b52fbbe5af06aab957d37405215f1f4ed6ecd

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear from the question how you are sending the token to the userInfo endpoint, Provided that the access token you have received is valid make sure that you are sending the token in the request header. Try the below curl command:-

```
curl 
     -X GET 
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>" 
     -H "Content-type: application/json" 
     http://{hostname}/auth/realms/{realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```